# Mathematical symbol for augment?

Tags: matrices, notation

I have a matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3\end{bmatrix}$$

that I want to augment with the squares of each entry along the columns. So the final result would be
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x^2_1 & x^2_2 & x^2_3\\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y^2_1 & y^2_2 & y^2_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there an expression to express this ? For example, I would write the following

$X \leftarrow  x_n^2 : \{n \subset \{1,2,3\}\}$

But that does not tell if I am augmenting along the column or the row. The arrow also does not specify what I do.

Comment: Consider using block matrix notation instead.

Comment: Perhaps you could introduce Hadamard product $\circ$ (the componentwise product) and call those matrices $[A\mid A\circ A]$ and $\left[\dfrac A{A\circ A}\right]$.